# Highlight the middle image in UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am Creating an app in which i put a UIScrollView as a image rotator in a single page we can see two image at a time like image scroller. image scroll as a horizantal manner.

Now the problem is i want to display middle image as a highlight. when image come around pixel 120 that image will be highlight or popover or like selected.

please help me... Thanx in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use two imageviews in rotation, i.e. set the image of the imageviews to next 2 images in your array. This will save a lot of memory than if you put say 10 imageview and populate them with images. Below is the code for photo scroller that displays one image at a time, you should be able to change the frame widths to display two according to your need.

Some constants:

```
//Portrait Image will have less width in landscape
#define kLandscapeImageHeight 300
#define kLandscapeImageWidth 208

//Landscape will have less height in portrait
#define kPortraitImageHeight 213
#define kPortraitImageWidth 320

#define kLandscapImageX 136
#define kPortraitImageY 134
```

Initializing:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([imageArray count]*320, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    if ([imageArray count] >= 1) {
        view1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];  

        UIImage *view1Image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageToOpen];

        //Photo was taken in portrait
        if (view1Image.size.width < view1Image.size.height) {
            view1.frame = CGRectMake(imageToOpen*320, 0, 320, 460);
        }
        //Photo was taken in landscape
        else {
            view1.frame = CGRectMake(imageToOpen*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
        }
        view1.image = view1Image;
        [scrollView addSubview:view1];

        view2 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

        if ([imageArray count] != 1) {
            if (imageToOpen < [imageArray count]-1) {

                UIImage *view2Image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:(imageToOpen+1)];

                //Photo was taken in portrait mode
                if (view2Image.size.width < view2Image.size.height) {
                    view2.frame = CGRectMake((imageToOpen+1)*320, 0, 320, scrollView.frame.size.height);
                }
                //Photo was taken in landscape mode
                else {
                    view2.frame = CGRectMake((imageToOpen+1)*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
                }
                view2.image = view2Image;
                [scrollView addSubview:view2];

            }
            else if (imageToOpen == [imageArray count]-1) {

                UIImage *view2Image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:(imageToOpen-1)];

                //Photo was taken in portrait mode
                if (view2Image.size.width < view2Image.size.height) {
                    view2.frame = CGRectMake((imageToOpen-1)*320, 0, 320, scrollView.frame.size.height);
                }
                //Photo was taken in landscape mode
                else {
                    view2.frame = CGRectMake((imageToOpen-1)*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
                }

                view2.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:imageToOpen-1];
                [scrollView addSubview:view2];
            }

        }
        //For some reason, same function with animated 'NO' behaves differently!!!
        [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:view1.frame animated:YES];
    }
```

Now implement the scrollView delegate method scrollViewDidScroll: in which you will identify which image is going to be the next one and highlight it. The 'nextView' always points to the imageView that is going to be displayed next on the screen. You can reduce the page width to 160 since you want two images displayed at a time:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *) scrollView {
    [self hideBars];

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    CGFloat pageWidth;
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
        pageWidth = 320;
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        pageWidth = 480;
    }
    float currPos = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x ;
    int selectedPage = roundf(currPos / pageWidth);    
    float truePosition = selectedPage*pageWidth;    
    int zone = selectedPage % 2;

    BOOL view1Active = zone == 0;

    UIImageView *nextView = view1Active ? view2 : view1;

    int nextpage = truePosition > currPos ? selectedPage-1 : selectedPage+1;

    if(nextpage >= 0 && nextpage < [imageArray count])
    {
        if((view1Active && nextpage == view1Index) || (!view1Active && nextpage == view2Index)) return;

        UIImage *nextViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:nextpage];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
            if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                nextView.frame = CGRectMake(nextpage*320, 0, 320, 480);
            }
            else {
                nextView.frame = CGRectMake(nextpage*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
            }

        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                nextView.frame = CGRectMake(nextpage*480+kLandscapImageX, 0, kLandscapeImageWidth, kLandscapeImageHeight);
            }
            else {
                nextView.frame = CGRectMake(nextpage*480, 0, 480, 300);
            }

        }
        nextView.image = nextViewImage;

        if(view1Active) view1Index = nextpage;
        else view2Index = nextpage;
    }
}
```

If your UI supports both orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;//(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);  

}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    int selectedPage = 0;
    //if scrollview is scrolled till the last page
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= ([imageArray count]-1)*320) {
            selectedPage = [imageArray count]-1;
        }
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= ([imageArray count]-1)*480) {
            selectedPage = [imageArray count]-1;
        }
    }
    if (selectedPage != [imageArray count]-1) {
        //condition doesnt apply for last page
        if (view1.frame.origin.x < view2.frame.origin.x) {
            //View 1 is at the front
            selectedPage = [imageArray indexOfObject:view1.image];
        }
        else {
            //View 2 is at the front
            selectedPage = [imageArray indexOfObject:view2.image];

        }
    }

    int zone = selectedPage % 2;
    BOOL view1Active = zone == 0;

    UIImageView *thisView = view1Active ? view1 : view2;
    UIImageView *nextView = view1Active ? view2 : view1;

    NSLog(@"Selected Page = %d", selectedPage);

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([imageArray count]*480, kLandscapeImageHeight);

        if ([imageArray count] != 1) {
            if (/*thisView.frame.origin.x < nextView.frame.origin.x && */(selectedPage+1) != [imageArray count]) {
                UIImage *nextViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage+1];

                if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage+1)*480+kLandscapImageX, 0, kLandscapeImageWidth, kLandscapeImageHeight);
                }
                else {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage+1)*480, 0, 480, 300);
                }

                [nextView setImage:nextViewImage];
            }
            else {
                UIImage *nextViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage-1];

                if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage-1)*480+kLandscapImageX, 0, kLandscapeImageWidth, kLandscapeImageHeight);
                }
                else {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage-1)*480, 0, 480, 300);
                }
                [nextView setImage:nextViewImage];
            }

        }        
        UIImage *thisViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage];

        if (thisViewImage.size.width < thisViewImage.size.height) {
            //[thisView setFrame:CGRectMake((selectedPage*480)+kLandscapImageX, 0, kLandscapeImageWidth, kLandscapeImageHeight)];
            thisView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage*480)+kLandscapImageX, 0, kLandscapeImageWidth, kLandscapeImageHeight);

        }
        else {
            [thisView setFrame:CGRectMake(selectedPage*480, 0, 480, 300)];
        }

        [thisView setImage:thisViewImage];

        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(selectedPage*480, 0) animated:YES];
    }

    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake([imageArray count]*320, 460);

        if ([imageArray count] != 1) {
            if (/*thisView.frame.origin.x < nextView.frame.origin.x && */(selectedPage+1) != [imageArray count]) {
                UIImage *nextViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage+1];

                if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                    //[nextView setFrame:CGRectMake((selectedPage+1)*320, 0, 320, 460)];
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage+1)*320, 0, 320, 460);

                }
                else {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage+1)*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
                }

                [nextView setImage:nextViewImage];
            }
            else {
                UIImage *nextViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage-1];

                if (nextViewImage.size.width < nextViewImage.size.height) {
                    [nextView setFrame:CGRectMake((selectedPage-1)*320, 0, 320, 460)];
                }
                else {
                    nextView.frame = CGRectMake((selectedPage-1)*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight);
                }

                [nextView setImage:nextViewImage];
            }

        }        
        UIImage *thisViewImage = [imageArray objectAtIndex:selectedPage];


        if (thisViewImage.size.width < thisViewImage.size.height) {
            [thisView setFrame:CGRectMake(selectedPage*320, 0, 320, 460)];
        }
        else {
            [thisView setFrame:CGRectMake(selectedPage*320, kPortraitImageY, 320, kPortraitImageHeight)];
        }
        [thisView setImage:thisViewImage];

        //For some reason, same function with animated 'NO' behaves differently!!!
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(selectedPage*320, 0) animated:YES];
        //this function doesnt work properly becase it doesnt dcroll if the rect is already visible. So photos load like half of one and half of the other
        //[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(selectedPage*320, 0, 320, scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];

    }   

}
```

Comment: hi, thanx.. what's view1Index? and is it pass array number in imageToOpen?

Comment: view1Index is calclated based on which image view1 is using. So if its has image number 5 in it then its index will be 5 (or 4 if you talk in terms of arrays)

Comment: hey your code does not working... it's going to crash every time even m change all the image size..